# TypeScript fails to infer correct type when having to specify a generic parameter type

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm wondering how to make TypeScript correctly infer the type of a generic when using a default type for a generic paramater or situations where you have to specify the generic parameter type.

Let me illustrate the issue, see the example below, here `res` is correctly typed as boolean.

```js
// res: boolean
function foo<R>(fn: () => R) {
    return fn();
}
const res = foo(() => true);
```

However as soon as I add another generic parameter (which I have to specify), now I can't get TypeScript to infer the result as boolean without me having to specify it explicitly. `R = unknown` yields the same result as when specifying unknown when calling the function `foo<string, unknown>(...)` in both cases `res` ends up being unknown.

Note that in the examples below it doesn't matter what the generic parameter X does, the point is that because you have to specify X in order to get some typing, it forces you to having to specify all of the generic types (in this case: `R` which we rather want to have inferred by TypeScript).

```js
// res: unknown
function foo<X, R>(fn: () => R) {
    return fn();
}
const res = foo<string, unknown>(() => true);

// res: unknown
function foo<X, R = unknown>(fn: () => R) {
    return fn();
}
const res = foo<string>(() => true);

// res: boolean - when not specifying types
function foo<X, R = unknown>(fn: () => R) {
    return fn();
}
const res = foo(() => true);

// res: boolean - I don't want to do this and specify the type directly
function foo<X, R>(fn: () => R) {
    return fn();
}
const res = foo<string, boolean>(() => true);
```

How can I get TypeScript to infer `R` correctly when forced to specify other generic parameters without me telling it the exact type?

I'm using TypeScript version 4.6.4

Comment: I do not understand the problem. What is the issue with using `const res = foo<string, boolean>(() => true);`?

Comment: I don't want to write the type `<boolean>` here, I want it to be inferred by TypeScript implicitly, just like when not specifying generic types

Comment: What is the purpose of `X` here?  It's type isn't used anywhere.  If you want advice other than "just get rid of `X`", could you [edit] the example so that `X` is used somewhere?  Maybe the return value of `foo()` could involve `X` in some way?  I *think* you're looking for partial type argument inference, which isn't directly supported, so you'd need a workaround like currying, but [that approach](https://tsplay.dev/w2pQ4m) really seems bizarre when `X` is just immediately discarded.  Help!  (If you reply or edit, please mention @jcalz in a comment so I'm notified)

Comment: Like [does this](https://tsplay.dev/mbKyBW) represent the problem you're having (in the `Problem` section)?  If so then maybe [edit] to use that example and I'll write up an answer explaining the situation and workarounds.  Let me know!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What X does doesn't really matter here, imagine it does something :p your currying solution seems to work! Interesting.

Comment: "Imagine it does something" doesn't quite count as a [mre].  Do you mind if I modify the question code so that it does something and then write up the answer?  And again, please mention @jcalz in your reply, or I will not be notified.

Comment: @jcalz that’s part of the point of the question (I admit the question is probably not ideally worded as I’m not sure of all the terms), it doesn’t matter what it does, an essential part of the problem is that because it’s there I have to specify all of the generics when calling the function. Lack of support for partial type inference, like you mentioned,  seems to be the answer. 

In my real code all it does is add typing to a parameter in a callback which the function takes as an argument. So imagine
‘’‘typescript function foo<X, R>(fn: (data: X) => R, arg: X) {
    return fn(arg);
}’’’

Comment: So instead of imagining, we can just [edit] the code in the question to be that version. I'm happy to do it for you and post an answer for it.  Does that work for you?  (still pls mention @jcalz so I get the little ➀ in my inbox)

Comment: @jcalz I see you are convinced making some use of X but I think it complicates the examples. I've specified in the question that what X does has no practical meaning here. I'm happy to accept your answer if you'd like to add one.

Comment: No, never mind. If we can’t agree on the state of the question then I’m not inclined to continue engaging.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the default generic types are not inferred is the lack of partial type argument inference in TypeScript. One way to work around it is to seperate the function call into two by a method called currying. This way you pass the required types to the first function while having the other type(s) inferred. An example:

```
function foo<X>() {
   return <R,>(fn: () => R) => fn();
}
// res === true
const res = foo()(() => true);
```